# How can Community ♦ revise tags?

Tags: support, tags

As an Objective-C / Cocoa(-Touch) developer I am quite annoyed of the way many users abuse the Xcode tag. They just add it to any question, either because they don't know the difference between the words «Cocoa» and «Xcode» or they seem to believe that the editor is important — what generally isnt the case.
So until today I literally deleted the Xcode tag from hundreds of question. Other users do the same.

But today I was highly surprised that it was [Community ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community), who deleted the tags Xcode and the iPhone (another often misused tag) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487021/how-do-i-get-this-if-statement-to-work) with the edit summary

> This question is not related to Xcode tag, code formatting

How can this automated user agent identify what tags are to be removed? And will it learn by our tag-revisions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An anonymous user suggested the edit, which was then approved by three registered members of the community.  [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) just takes credit when there's no one else to assign it to.